# How does 移して 運ぶ function here?

Tags: grammar

The sentence in question:
運転再開の見通しは立っていないということで、ＪＲ東日本は止まっている列車の乗客を別の列車に移して運ぶとともにトラブルの原因を調べています。

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180617/k10011481821000.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-main_001

My attempt at translation:
"About the forecast for the resumption of service, none is standing so far and JR EastJapan is investigating the problem while also carrying over passengers from the stopped train to another train."

My main issue here is the 移して運ぶ because it seems to me that these two words basically form "one word"/"one meaning", but jisho doesnt list any entry for such a composition. Therefore I wanted to ask wether Im correct or completely misinterpreted it.

Furthermore, I also feel rather unsure about my understanding とともに. I read about it here http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E5%85%B1%E3%81%AB-totomoni/

"年を取ると共に体が弱ってきたようだ。
As I become older, my body becomes weaker."

And to me it seemed like the only viable option here, but I might be wrong of course.

Comment: Not directly related to your questions, but what do you mean by "none is standing so far"?

Comment: "there is none" is meant by this. At least in my native tongue german "none stands so far" can refer to appointments and say that there is none (yet). I must admit I dont know wether this works in english and/or japanese as well, so I just gave it a shot xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「移{うつ}して運{はこ}ぶ」

is ***not*** a set phrase of any sort, which is why it is not listed even in the largest dictionary.  It is simply connecting two separate verbs by using the te-form.  It just means:

> 「移す & 運ぶ」 (to transfer & transport)

**"JR is tranferring the passengers from the train in trouble to a new one AND taking/transporting them (someplace)."**

And your understanding of 「とともに」 seems good.  It is used to talk about two things happening simultaneously.